# LeBlender grid editor is not available when adding grid to page

Tags: umbraco

I tried adding a new LeBlender Grid Editor in Umbraco 7.3.1 under "Developer -> Grid Editors", assigned it a cshtml-file in the "Render" property (via Visual Studio), but when I create a new page and want to add the new grid editor it is not available in the list of grid editors. If I go to "Settings -> Partial Views -> Grid -> Editors" I can see the cshtml file that I created in Visual Studio and it appears to be valid.

Is there something else I need to do, e.g. add the new grid editor to a list of available grid editors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that your editor is **not allowed** to be used inside your grid configuration or the **cache** of file used to keep configurations (grid.editors.config.js from /config directory) is causing the problem.

First of all, to enable editor on specific grid data type, you need to specify it inside the grid configuration. So first of all, check if the editor or "all editors" option is set up for a row configuration on which you want to use your custom editor created with **LeBlender** (for help check: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/Grid-Layout/configuring-the-grid-layout-datatype). For example, I needed to set the checkbox for my ***Test*** grid editor to be used on my ***Frontpage*** grid during the tests.

[image: Enabling custom editor to be used inside the row grid configuration]

If you'll still be experiencing the problem, set ***debug="true"*** in web.config what will cause the aggresive caching in the backoffice to be little less painfull for developing your website locally. Of course, don't forget to set it up back for ***false*** when you'll be pushing your website to the further (and especially live) enviroments.

Comment: you saved my neck :-) The issue was that I missed the part where you need to mark the editor as allowed for the row configuration. I kind of suspected that to be the issue, but with that said I never realized I had to click on the cell itself in order to configure the editors. Bounty will be awarded in 7 hours along with my gratitude

Comment: awesome! glad that it helped :) it's really powerfull and according to the grid usage - it's really important to limit possibilities for editors to make our solution editors-proof ;)